# Project using only specific functions

Tags: python-3.x

Input is "*Enter a word or integer*" 
If it is `word` it should print"*Its all word*"
If it is `integer` it should print "*Its all integer*"
If something else it should print "*its nor word nor integer*"
If it's greater than 99 it should print "*Its greater than 99*"
And Imp: the code can be made only by using `DEF FUNC, WHILE, IF ELSE, ISALPHA, ISDIGIT, INT()`.

This is my code:

```
def string_analysis(string):
    while True:

        enter = input("Enter word or integer: ")

        if enter.isalpha == False:
            return "Only integer or word"
              if enter.isdigit == False:
                  return "Its not alphabet"
            elif enter < 99:
                print("Its greater than 99")

print(string_analysis(enter))
```

It's not giving me the expected output. Please help.

Comment: You need to fix your indentation first.

Comment: You also aren't *calling* either of the methods; it's `enter.isalpha()` and `enter.isdigit()`.

Comment: i know, i run this code before with proper indentation but its not giving me proper output, just its looping with the input

Comment: u mean, print(string_analysis(enter.isdigit))?

Comment: No, I mean `if enter.isalpha() == False:` (or preferably, `if not enter.isalpha():`.

Comment: Can you please tell what are the. things. that i have to fix in my code

Comment: i didnt used "Not" becoz i am not allowed to use tats y

Comment: can u help pls??

Comment: what if it's an integer and greater than 99? should it print both?

Comment: it should print("its greater than 99")

Answer (score 0):

You have a ‘While true:’ loop but there doesn’t seem to be a ‘run = False’ statement or anything like that, hence why your code is continually looping

Comment: what shall i do in this case pls?

Comment: Add a run variable at the start then you can While run == true and set it to False afterwards

Comment: But do you really need a While loop In this function?

Comment: Also just noticed you used < 99 rather than > 99

Comment: i have to use While statement, its a project so yes

Comment: And on the first line where you say string_analysis(string) I don’t think you need the (string) in brackets as you dont call it in your function so that may be confusing your code

Comment: Ok then try the run Boolean variable

Comment: thats what i used here, true or false.

Comment: But you need to add a set to false at the end or the code will continue to loop

Comment: i gave the argument names as enter_1 and enter_2 and now i am calling func by  print(string_analysis(enter.isdigit(), enter.isalpha()), its giving me error "Unused argument enter_1 and enter_2"

Comment: ya i ll do that now when i run the code it just ask Enter integer or word and then when i enter it doesnot show any result it asks again

Comment: If run = False doesn’t work then I don’t know how to solve this problem sorry

Comment: in the very end u mean, i mean after calling the function?

Comment: i dont think so there is any function called RUN in python

Comment: No at the end of the while loop but still in it (in the function)

Comment: I don’t think there’s a RUN function I just meant make a variable and put it at the end of the while loop (but still in it - check your indentation)